# http request put not working with json format

Tags: c#, put, rest

I am trying to call an update api with the given parameter at the end of the url, however the update was unsuccessful and returns me an exception.

Here is my sample code for PUT method:

```
string result = "";
string json = "{" +
        "\"ID\": " + 343336 + ",  " +
        "\"occurence\": " + 0 + ",  " +
        "\"user\": " + "Juan Dela Cruz" + ",  " +
        "\"comments\":" + "Test comments" +
        "}";


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl/Update/343336");
request.Method = "PUT";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
    try
    {
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    }

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
}

console.WriteLine(result);
```

I already put a try catch on my code and it was returning me this error:

```
Unrecognized token: was expecting (true, false or null)
```

Any comments/suggestions TIA.

Comment: The JSON `{"ID": 343336,  "occurence": 0,  "user": Juan Dela Cruz,  "comments":Test comments}` you provide is invalid. You can check it using e.g. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). You are missing the quotation marks on string values.

Comment: I got it working now. appreciate you help for pointing me on this json validator.